# Why is this SQL (SUBSTR) code is incorrect?

Tags: sql

The task:
Can you return all of the robots that are located in NY?

[image]

my code:

```
SELECT * FROM robots
WHERE SUBSTR(location, LEN(location)-2, 2) = 'NY';
```

A working code:

```
SELECT * FROM robots
WHERE SUBSTR(location, -2, 2) = 'NY';
```

Why LEN doesn't work well in my code?

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate on "LEN doesn't work well". Do you get an error message or there are no results? Which SQL implementation are you using?

Comment: Why not opt for Where Location Like '%NY'    ... no need for record level calcuations

Comment: @John Cappelletti  - If any location have "Ny" It will fetch wrong records, Please note the 5th record from the image "Nyack, NY"

Comment: @GuruprakashC - `LIKE '%NY'` matches any number of characters, then `N`, then `Y`, then *no more characters*. It only matches strings that *end* with `NY`, and it's not unreasonable given the sample data that all `Location` fields are expected to end with a state code. (Of course, it would arguably be better if states were explicitly modelled rather than having to be extracted from a textual `location` column, but that's out of scope here)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that [according to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx):

> *start*
>
> Is an integer or bigint expression that specifies where the returned characters start. (The numbering is 1 based, meaning that the first character in the expression is 1).

So, `SUBSTR("NY, NY", LEN("NY, NY")-2, 2)` evaluates to `SUBSTR("NY, NY", 4, 2)`, which is:

```
NY, NY
123456
   ^^
```

Your returned string is `" N"`, so `SUBSTR(location, LEN(location)-1, 2)`, subtracting 1 only, should give you the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. May be some space location have before and after text. So trim the text before using substring.

```
--For MS SQL
SELECT * FROM robots
WHERE SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(location)),LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(location)))-1,LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(location)))) = 'NY';
```

For Oracle. we have to use length keyword not LEN. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the call to SUBSTR will stop the query selecting/using the appropriate Indexes.

```
 SELECT * FROM robots
 WHERE SUBSTR(location, -2, 2) = 'NY';
```

In terms of performance you may be better using

```
LIKE '%, NY'
```

in MS SQL.